# How to print a string in x86 real-mode non-OS assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, osdev

I am trying to implement a function which tries to print string in 16-bit mode seen on QEmu:
kernel.c file:

```
void main()
{
 char* str = "Hello World!";
 printString(str); 
}
```

The printString function is defined in another file printString.c:

```
int printString(char* string)
{ 
 int i = 0;
 while (*(string + i) != '\0')
   {
    char al = *(string + i);
    char ah = 0xe;
    int ax = ah * 256 + al;
    interrupt(0x10,ax,0,0,0);
    i++;
   }
 return i;
}
```

The interrupt function calls BIOS interrupt, as given in the first argument of the function with other arguments specifying respectively the contents of ax, bx, cx and dx registers. Here is the code

```
.global _interrupt
_interrupt:
push bp
mov bp, sp
push si
push ds
mov ax, #0x100
mov ds, ax
mov ax, [bp + 0x4]
mov si, #intr
mov [si + 1], al
pop ds
mov ax, [bp + 0x6]
mov bx, [bp + 0x8]
mov cx, [bp + 0xa]
mov dx, [bp + 0xc]
intr: int #0x0
pop si
pop bp
ret
```

I compile the .c files using the command:

```
bcc -ansi -c -o <name.o> <name.c>
```

And link them using:

```
ld86 -o kernel -d kernel.o interrupt.o printString.o
```

Instead of printing "Hello World!", the program prints "S" on the screen. I loaded the kernel.c file at the address 0x1000. I saw the dis-assembly of the code:

```
0x1000: push   %bp
0x1001: mov    %sp,%bp
0x1003: push   %di
0x1004: push   %si
0x1005: dec    %sp
0x1006: dec    %sp
0x1007: mov    $0xc8,%bx
0x100a: mov    %bx,-0x6(%bp)
0x100d: pushw  -0x6(%bp)
0x1010: call   0x1058
```

For the pointer to be passed to the printString function (in kernel.c file) the argument passed is 0xc8 which contains 0xf000ff53. Thus 53, which is the ASCII code for S gets printed on the screen.
How should I pass the string to the printString function and why doesn't the above code works?
Please tell me if I need to give more explanation.

Comment: Sounds like `ds` isn't set up properly.

Comment: OMG! 16-bit assembly!!!  brings back bad memories from the 90s!

Comment: @Jester You were right about ds resister and setting it to 0x100 made it work. But I did not understand why this worked. Even though I changed the ds register to 0x100 the above mov instruction i.e., mov $c8, %bx did not change and the value written to %bx register is again 0xc8. What is the difference between these codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation

- I got your code to work after setting up the **DS** data segment
  register early in `kernel.c` with inline assembly.
- You're loading your kernel image at `0x1000` and building your code so that it thinks it starts at address `0x0`. Thus for data access to work, you need to setup the **DS** data segment register to add `0x1000` to memory addresses in data access instructions.

  - For example, to access the first byte of your "Hello World!" string located at offset `0xc8` of the kernel image, you need to access physical memory address `0x10c8`. By setting **DS** to `0x100`, an access to data memory at address `0xc8` is translated into an access to physical address `$ds*0x10 + 0xc8 == 0x10c8`, i.e. the address we want.
  - Read the first half of [x86 segmentation](http://wiki.osdev.org/Segmentation) for the details.
  - The memory access happens in the `*(string + i)` expression in `printString()` thus stepping over the assembler level instructions of the `printString()` loop in GDB should also help. You were focusing on the wrong code by disassembling `main()` because you didn't understand x86 segmentation.
- I'm not sure how you're loading and running the
  code at address `0x1000` with Qemu. In my setup below, I'm loading the code via GDB and have a small boot sector that just jumps to that address.

### kernel.c

```
void main()
{
#asm
    mov ax, #0x100
    mov ds, ax
#endasm
    char* str = "Hello World!";
    printString(str); 
}
```

### printString.c

```
int printString(char* string)
{ 
 int i = 0;
 while (*(string + i) != '\0')
   {
    char al = *(string + i);
    char ah = 0xe;
    int ax = ah * 256 + al;
    interrupt(0x10,ax,0,0,0);
    i++;
   }
 return i;
}
```

### interrupt.asm

```
.global _interrupt
_interrupt:
push bp
mov bp, sp
push si
mov ax, [bp + 0x4]
mov si, #intr
mov [si + 1], al
mov ax, [bp + 0x6]
mov bx, [bp + 0x8]
mov cx, [bp + 0xa]
mov dx, [bp + 0xc]
intr: int #0x0
pop si
pop bp
ret
```

### boot.asm

```
.global _main
_main:
mov ax, #0x1000
jmp ax
```

### bootsector-create

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Create an x86 boot sector
# Pad file to 512 bytes, insert 0x55, 0xaa at end of file

import sys
import os

def program_name():
    return os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])

def print_usage_exit():
    sys.stderr.write('usage: %s IN_FILENAME OUT_FILENAME\n' % (program_name(),))
    sys.exit(2)

def main(args):
    try:
        (in_filename, out_filename) = args
    except ValueError:
        print_usage_exit()

    buf = bytearray(512)
    f = open(in_filename, 'rb')
    f.readinto(buf)
    buf[510] = 0x55
    buf[511] = 0xaa
    fout = open(out_filename, 'wb')
    fout.write(buf)
    fout.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

### kernel.gdb

```
set confirm 0
set pagination 0
set architecture i8086

target remote localhost:1234
set disassemble-next-line 1

monitor system_reset
delete

restore kernel binary 0x1000
continue
```

### GNUmakefile

```
DERVED_FILES := kernel kernel.o interrupt.o printString.o boot boot.o bootsect

.PHONY: all
all: boot kernel

bootsect: boot
    ./bootsector-create $< $@

boot: boot.o
    ld86 -o $@ -s -d $+

kernel: kernel.o interrupt.o printString.o
    ld86 -o $@ -s -d $+

%.o: %.c
    bcc -ansi -c -o $@ $<

%.o: %.asm
    as86 -o $@ $<

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(DERVED_FILES)

.PHONY: emulator
emulator: bootsect
    qemu-system-x86_64 -s -S bootsect

.PHONY: gdb
gdb:
    gdb -q -x kernel.gdb
```

### Sample Session

```
$ make emulator
(In a separate terminal)
$ make gdb
```

Comment: Thanks.... But I did not understand how this worked. Even though I changed the ds register to 0x100 the above mov instruction i.e., `mov $c8, %bx` did not change and the value written to %bx register is again 0xc8. What is the difference between these codes?

Comment: @sarthak See the link in the answer about how segmentation works. In short, each memory access has an associated segment which is used in the address calculation. If you change the segment the calculated address also changes.

Comment: @sarthak, read the first half of http://wiki.osdev.org/Segmentation If you know x86 assembly, stepping over the `printString()` loop at the assembler level in GDB should also help.

Comment: @sarthak, I've updated my answer with a more elaborate explanation. Hopefully it helps :)